# Struct of struct initialization in .h on VisualStudio C++

Tags: c++, struct

I'm porting a linux code on Windows and i'm stucked on initialization of packet style struct..

Here original code of protocol.h :

```
struct header
{
    uint8_t type;  
    uint8_t ext;   
    uint8_t seqno;
    uint8_t notused
};

struct packet
{
    struct header head;

    packet(uint8_t t, uint8_t e, uint8_t s) : head( { t, e, s, 0 } ) <== Error here
    { }
};
```

with :
error C2059: syntax error : ')' 
error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Could you tell me some advice ?

Thanks a lot

Seb

Comment: You should probably upgrade your Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you have? If it's new enough you could try e.g. `head{ t, e, s, 0 }`, or drop the brackets and try `head( t, e, s, 0 )`

Comment: Works fine in VS2013, after adding the missing ;, you are probably using an older version that doesn't support C++11 initializers yet.

Comment: I'am on Visual Studio 2012... I will try to update too...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is in my opinion just to add a constructor to struct `header`:

```
struct header
{
    uint8_t type;  
    uint8_t ext;   
    uint8_t seqno;
    uint8_t notused;
    header(uint8_t t, uint8_t e, uint8_t s, uint8_t n)
        : type(t), ext(e), seqno(s), notused(n)
    { }
};

struct packet
{
    header head;

    packet(uint8_t t, uint8_t e, uint8_t s) : head(t, e, s, 0)
    { }
};
```